# Change jTextField from another class

Tags: java, swing, class, jtextfield

I have two different classes which creates two Panel's A & B. B is initiated after a button is click on A.
I want to change the a jTextField in B, when a button is clicked on A.

***Code of A***

```
private final B myB = new B();

public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new A().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Initiation of B**

```
private void btnIPCStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        launch.B.main(null);
    }
```

Change of jTextField in **B**

```
private void btnBattRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                              
    {      
        **// Calling Via Variable**                                                  
        myB.txtSystemOutput.setText("Low Battery"); // **NOT Working**

        **// Calling Via Setter**
        myB.setTextSystemOutput("Low Battery"); // **NOT Working**

        **// Calling Via Direct Variable**
        project.B.txtSystemOutput.setText("Low Battery"); // **NOT Working**
    }
```

---

***Code of B***

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new B().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

public void setTextSystemOutput(String value)
    {
        txtSystemOutput.setText(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to create B by calling its static main method as that is unnecessary and harmful since it isolates the B visualized instance from your A object. Instead create a B instance in A, create it in the non-static world, and this way, A can call instance variables on B as needed.

So change method to:

```
private void btnIPCStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
   myB.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the answer. The answer by @MadProgrammer works too.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `launch.B.main(null);`, create an instance of `B` and pass it a reference to what ever it needs in order to tell you something needs to be update.

You should resist the temptation to let `B` or `A` make modifications directly to each other as this opens them up to a lot of potential risk and tightly couples your code, better to use a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) of some kind

Based on your example, `B` needs to monitor some state change in `A`, so `B` would need to "listener" to `A` and update it's state based on changes that `A` announces

Comment: This worked also. The link [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) was quite insightful.